# How to return stream with non-static Query?

Tags: rust-sqlx

I need to write a function that returns a `BoxStream` of records from a dynamically built SQL (e.g. using `QueryBuilder`). The problem is that the stream references the SQL which causes "cannot return value referencing local variable" error. AFAIK there's no owned Query in `sqlx`, so I don't see a way to return stream other than to implement my own wrapper. Is there more elegant way?